# How can I run an AutoHotkey script on C++ code?

Tags: c++, windows, autohotkey

I am developing an open source desktop application in C++, and I need to run this AutoHotkey script inside C++ code, how can I make it?

```
Acc_Caret := Acc_ObjectFromWindow(WinExist("A"), OBJID_CARET := 0xFFFFFFF8)
Caret_Location := Acc_Location(Acc_Caret)
x = %A_CaretX%
y = %A_CaretY%

WinGetPos, Xc, Yc,,, A

msgbox, Act at %Xc%`,%Yc% 
msgbox % Caret_Location.x "`n" Caret_Location.y
msgbox % x "`n" y

return

Acc_Init()
{
    Static  h
    If Not  h
        h:=DllCall("LoadLibrary","Str","oleacc","Ptr")
}
Acc_ObjectFromWindow(hWnd, idObject = -4)
{
    Acc_Init()
    If  DllCall("oleacc\AccessibleObjectFromWindow", "Ptr", hWnd, "UInt", idObject&=0xFFFFFFFF, "Ptr", -VarSetCapacity(IID,16)+NumPut(idObject==0xFFFFFFF0?0x46000000000000C0:0x719B3800AA000C81,NumPut(idObject==0xFFFFFFF0?0x0000000000020400:0x11CF3C3D618736E0,IID,"Int64"),"Int64"), "Ptr*", pacc)=0
    Return  ComObjEnwrap(9,pacc,1)
}
Acc_Location(Acc, ChildId=0, byref Position="") { ; adapted from Sean's code
    try Acc.accLocation(ComObj(0x4003,&x:=0), ComObj(0x4003,&y:=0), ComObj(0x4003,&w:=0), ComObj(0x4003,&h:=0), ChildId)
    catch
        return
    Position := "x" NumGet(x,0,"int") " y" NumGet(y,0,"int") " w" NumGet(w,0,"int") " h" NumGet(h,0,"int")
    return  {x:NumGet(x,0,"int"), y:NumGet(y,0,"int"), w:NumGet(w,0,"int"), h:NumGet(h,0,"int")}
}
```

(msgbox are there just to debug)

Comment: Probably via `ShellExecute` - that's probably the simplest way.

Comment: @Dai yes, that's an option but it is for an emoji picker, so it need to be faster as posible (like `Win + .` ; Keeping the app in background and executing this script to determine where it's going to appear). The `Acc` lib for AutoHotkey implements `oleacc.h`, so there has to be a simpler way.

Comment: If latency/speed is an issue, probably the way to go is to implement that script directly in C++. You might also be able to copy AHK's source code, include it in your own, and then use it to execute the script from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using the dll should work see https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=34779&p=160687 Perhaps you could see how [this](https://github.com/echristopherson/ahk_drb_demo) Ruby/Ahk integration worked.